# Hausdorff Space that is a non Normal Hausdorff Space

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

Can someone give me an example of a Hausdorff space (i.e $T_2$),
that is not a normal Hausdorff space (i.e $T_4$)?

Comment: What's the distinction between a space and a SPACE?

Comment: Try searching [here](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=146).

Comment: The Sorgenfrey plane is not normal but Hausdorff.

Comment: The [half-disc topology](http://books.google.com/books?id=DkEuGkOtSrUC&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=half+disc+topology&source=bl&ots=3iIzQNzXn2&sig=3tUIsZpknU_Y7C-X5vac457fMjo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YxLrUf26HI689QTbxIG4BA&ved=0CEIQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=half%20disc%20topology&f=false) is an  example which is easy to analyze.

Comment: Sorgenfrey is T4

Comment: and David thank you very much you :D

Comment: @EliElizirov: The Sorgenfrey line, not the square of it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are many examples. One simple one is the [$K$-*topology*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-topology) on $\Bbb R$. Let $K=\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$. Let

$$\mathscr{B}=\{(a,b):a,b\in\Bbb R\text{ and }a<b\}\cup\{(a,b)\setminus K:a,b\in\Bbb R\text{ and }a<b\}\;;$$

then $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for the $K$-topology. This topology is finer than the usual one, so it is certainly Hausdorff. It is not regular, because in this topology $K$ is a closed set, $0\notin K$, and $0$ and $K$ cannot be separated by disjoint open sets.

Another fairly simple example is the [*Sorgenfrey plane*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_plane). [This post](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/a-note-on-the-sorgenfrey-line/) from Dan Ma’s Topology Blog gives much information on it, including a proof that it is not normal.

Comment: More generally, we can always construct the smallest topology containing the given topology $\tau$ and a set $A$ by defining $\tau(A)=\{U\cup(V\cap A)\mid U,V\in\tau\}.$